# average miscalculated on pagination/export

Tags: jqgrid, jqpivot

I am having trouble when using aggregators with avg because it keeps dividing the last result by the quantity every time pagination goes back or export occurs.

So the 1st time on the page/export the avg is right and every subsequent export/page back the last result gets divided again by the number of rows.

That only happens with more than one xDimension.

Also in the export at each export each summary header is repeated X times exported.

Anyone experienced that? jqgrid 5.3.0.

Edit: (image removed, example removed)

Comment: We need a true example with code and data in order to help and no pictures - they don't help at all.

Comment: added working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example help to resolve the problem. Thank you. This was a bug and it [is fixed](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/db3f4538fed57ee908bc4cb8e1b60abe5751c959). You can get the fix from GitHub the code is rebuild ed